# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'labda expression' and 'lambda expression'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, controller

I have this code at controller of MVC project:

```
public ActionResult Report(DateTime? datumOD, DateTime? datumDO)
{
    var ponudis = db.ponudis.Include(s => s.ponudaDets).Where(x => x.odobreno);
    if (datumOD.HasValue && datumDO.HasValue)
    {
        ponudis = db.ponudis.Where( (c => c.datum >= datumOD) && (n => n.datum <= datumDO) );

    }
    return View(ponudis.ToList());
}
```

But i have the following error:

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to opeands of type 'labda expression' and 'lambda expression'

What is wrong here?

Comment: You have two lambda expressions and are trying to "and" them. It's a fair guess that is what is wrong. What is it you are actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: you have a logic operation with two lambdas, try `db.ponudis.Where(c => c.datum >= datumOD && c.datum <= datumDO);` instead which is one lamda that checks for elements within the date range

Comment: @ r3bel yes, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments already, you're trying to add two lambda expressions together. I'm guessing you're trying to achieve something like the following:

```
ponudis = db.ponudis.Where(c => c.datum >= datumOD && c.datum <= datumDO);
```